# SQL Server - Create a trigger that will log to an alert when quantity for a product gets to 1

Tags: sql-server, triggers, alert

I have been asked to write a query/script that will cause what is described in the title of the question to happen. Here is what is being asked:

> You have been asked to create a trigger that will log to an alert
>   table when your quantity on hand for any product is down to 1.
>
> Create the following:
>
> 1. Script to create the alert table.  (It needs to have at least a datetime stamp, alert type, alert description).
> 2. Script to create the trigger for where you keep track of inventory.

So, what do I do? I've looked everywhere to see if I could figure it out on my own, but I'm not having any luck. If I could receive any help with this it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: do as the question ask. 1. create the alert table, 2. write the trigger

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is vague as there aren't a lot of specifics involved in the question, however the concept will work. Hope it helps!

Create a table to hold the alerts as follows

```
CREATE TABLE AlertTable(
ProductID int, 
ProductName varchar(255),
AlertDate DateTime DEFAULT GETDATE(),
AlertType varchar(50),
AlertDescription varchar(255)
);
```

Then create a trigger on your stock table to insert products into the table which have a StockOnHand value of 1 in the inserted table. (ie somebody has changed the table and now there is only 1 item left)

```
CREATE TRIGGER StockAlert
ON StockTable
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO AlertTable
SELECT ProductID, ProductName, 'Low Stock', 
'There is only 1 ' + ProductName + ' left' 
FROM inserted
WHERE StockOnHand = 1
END
GO
```

Comment: The first part worked, but I'm having a problem with the insert into part on the 2nd is showing that AlertTable is not an object. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi Michael, It may be down to the Database and Schema that you are using not being the default for your login. Try dropping the table and recreating with a more qualified Name. i.e `CREATE TABLE DatabaseName.SchemaName.AlertTable`. Then you can use the same create trigger statement, but just reference the qualified name. So if your Database is called Company and your schema is the default dbo, you will use `CREATE TABLE Company.dbo.AlertTable` and then in the trigger use `CREATE TRIGGER StockAlert ON Company.dbo.StockTable`. Let me know of any more issues :) thanks... Phil